# object-rest-spread is not allowed trailing commas in babel 7

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

This is my `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.0.1",
    "@babel/node": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "4.2.5",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.9.3",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "webpack": "4.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.8"
  },
```

`babel-loader` 7 is not allowed trailing commas in object-rest-spread.

```
const {
  number,
  ...other, // A trailing comma is not permitted after the rest element 
} = this.state;
```

[image]

But I should use trailing commas in object-rest-spread in babel7
How to use it? Any plugins?

Comment: Why do you need to use trailing commas?

Comment: i upgrade my project. so i should fix all code.. so i need  like plugin...

Answer (score 3):

Trailing commas for object rest is not supported in EcmaScript standard, i.e. it's not valid code. If you previously had commas there then I believe the right way to fix the syntax errors is to remove the commas where they're not supposed to be.

Please, read this discussion for more details (you can follow referenced issues there as well to have the full picture): https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/issues/47